# Django Form says the field is required when it is filled

Tags: django, forms

I have removed some useless branch from my git and now one function on my website does not work. When I am trying to add recipe as normall user when every field is filled, i push the button "add recipe" it shows that ingrediend field is required so Django treats this one like it would be empty.. but it is not.

View:

```
def add_recipe(request):

     add_recipe = RecipeForm(request.POST)
     print(add_recipe['ingredients'].value())
     if add_recipe.is_valid():
          add_recipe.save()
          return redirect('success_added_recipe')

     return render(request, 'drinks/add_recipe.html', {'RecipeForm': add_recipe})
```

Form:

```
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['recipe_name', 'preparation', 'ingredients', 'recipe_image']
```

debug.log

```
(0.000) SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"; args=()
(0.001) SELECT "drinks_ingredient"."id", "drinks_ingredient"."ingredient_name" FROM "drinks_ingredient" WHERE "drinks_ingredient"."id" IN (12); args=(12,)
(0.000) SELECT "drinks_ingredient"."id", "drinks_ingredient"."ingredient_name" FROM "drinks_ingredient"; args=()
"POST /accounts/add_recipe/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1637
(0.002)
```

model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
  recipe_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='')


  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

template:

```
<h1>Add recipe</h1>

<form method="post" action="{% url 'add_recipe' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{RecipeForm}}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the `Recipe` model and your form template?

Comment: yes, I have udated it now upper. :)

Comment: Add can you share the template for the form?

Comment: I have added it. I can see now that in pycharm all other templates has some green letter H, but this one add_recipe miss it..

Comment: Do you know how to solve it..?